# How to refer to a column table in a sumifs? I get an invalid error

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

I want to do a sumifs and as my sumrange I want to refer to a column of one of my tables.

My table name is: ENERO
My column name is: MONTO

So I want to put my sumrange as follows:

ENERO[MONTO]; ...

But I get this:

[image: Invalid Error]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Interesting, I get a similar "error" (in my case it's #VALUE!) when I tested, but I filled in the rest of the formula wizard and it calculates the answer. IMO, this is a bug and you should submit it to Microsoft for remediation.

Comment: @Caterina ,,,, this should be the formula `=SUMIF(Table8[Year],2023,Table8[Days])` ,, if use Formula,, Insert then for Range and SUM Range you find #VALUE error,,, but get the result also !!

Comment: @Caterina,,, if enter formula using KB then use either,,, `=SUMIF(Table8[Year],2023,Table8[Days])` or    `=SUMIFS(Table8[Days],Table8[Year],2023)`  both works !!

Comment: @Caterina ,,, the reason is ,,,the variable provided in the formula is not a supported type or when the cell referred to in the formula is invalid,,, but in this case the issue is with Cell REFERENCE pattern for the TABLE,,, `Table8[Year]`  or `Table8[[#All],[Year]]`  non of them is valid format for FUNCTION ARGUMENTS,,,, **even though returns correct results** ,,,,, if enter data range like A2:A10 never get error !!